# delete a specific lines between two symbols in .txt file (php)

Tags: php, file

How can i delete lines in  text file which are between two dollars  with php :

```
lorem upsum  lorem upsum 
lorem upsum  lorem upsum lorem upsum
$

lorem upsum
lorem upsum
lorem upsum

$
lorem upsum
lorem upsum
lorem upsum

lorem upsum
lorem upsum
lorem upsum
```

thank you

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: You'll have to read the file in php transforming it into an array, so each line of your file is a position vector, compare equal if you walk by replacing or removing

Comment: @Dexxtz good idea,can give me an example please ?

Comment: @Bouraoui Consult my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wasn't an easy task, but this works.

```
$source_file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$source = preg_replace('/(\$)(.*)(\$)/s',"$1 $3", $source_file);

file_put_contents('file.txt', $source);
echo $source;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is this, what you can do to verify the condition string has $ and do something.

If you do not change uncomment the line that counts strings

```
<?php
    $archive = "text.txt";
    $search = "$";
    $arrayArchive = file($archive);

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arrayArchive); $i++){
        //echo $arrayArchive[$i] . ' - ' . strlen($arrayArchive[$i]) . ' == ' . $search . ' - ' . strlen($search) . '<br />';
        if($arrayArchive[$i] == $search){
            $arrayArchive[$i] = '';
        }
    }   
    file_put_contents($archive, implode("", $arrayArchive));
?>
```