# replace string contained between two characters

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

I have a string like:

```
www.mydomain.com/product/$ID_PRODUCT$/ID_$ID_PRODUCT$
```

what I need is replace strings contained between '$' and '$', also deleting the strings delimiters ( which is '$' ) obtaining something like:

```
www.mydomain.com/product/1234/ID_1234
```

Thanks,

EDIT:
Trying

```
$new_string = preg_replace('/(\$)(.*)(\$)/s', product->id, $string);
```

But it does not handle the second expression...

The demo of @stribizhev , given in comments below, worked for me!

Comment: It might turn out a rather basic task, did you try anything? If you just need to replace `$`+`not $ (1 or more)`+`$` with one value, it is really simple.

Comment: yes, I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875913/simple-how-to-replace-all-between-with-php ok, help me mate

Comment: The accepted answer there features a "wrong" regex. But you need a negated character class, true.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25977999/delete-a-specific-lines-between-two-symbols-in-txt-file-php). And use a negated character class `[^$]+` instead of `.*`. Post the attempt if you fail to obtain expected result.

Comment: You can do this simply with str_replace

Comment: Have a look at [the demo](http://ideone.com/Ff6ka4).

Comment: Check [`\$[^$]+\$`](https://regex101.com/r/wH3zI3/1)

Comment: @stribizhev demo ( http://ideone.com/Ff6ka4 ) worked for me! Thanks mate.

Comment: If the template string contains a single placeholder (`$PRODUCT_ID$`, f.e.) then you don't need `regexp`. Just use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). If there are many possible placeholders then you need a way to identify what placeholder was found in order to know what replacement to use. [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) doesn't help in this case. You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) but, again, `str_replace()` is enough, easier to use and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to work:

```
<?php
$a = 'www.mydomain.com/product/$ID_PRODUCT$/ID_$ID_PRODUCT$';
echo preg_replace('/[$][a-zA-Z_]+[$]/',"1234",$a);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/hIKOoK)